# VeraCrypt dualboot 2x Windows 11 on the same disk

Tags: encryption, multi-boot, windows-11, disk-encryption, veracrypt

I have Laptop with an SSD where I have created 2 partitions and installed Windows 11 Home on both of them. One of the partitions is already encrypted with VeraCrypt and I can easily boot both systems after authenticating in the VeraCrypt bootloader.

I would like to also encrypt the 2nd partition. If I simply install VeraCrypt on the other system, it will overwrite the existing bootloader which might give me issues when trying to boot the other system.

What would be the best approach to get the 2nd partition encrypted as well?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and it looks like it cannot be done with VeraCrypt 1.25.9. VeraCrypt will give you two additional warnings when you try to encrypt the second OS and it tells you that this setup is not supported.

That's odd, because VeraCrypt seems to support multi-boot systems to a certain degree. The help even claims to support two Windows operating systems as a dual-boot setup. But I think they only support multi-boot setups, where only one system is encrypted with VeraCrypt.

Possible workarounds:

- If it suits you, you can think about the setup of a [hidden operating system](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Hidden%20Operating%20System.html) to end up with two VeraCrypt encrypted operating systems.
- Encrypt the other - maybe less important - system with BitLocker. Then you will have two distinct bootloaders for each system and both systems will be encrypted.